# Actions on Google: Unable to Close Convo in DialogFlow Fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am on ActionOnGoogle V2 SDK, and using Firebase Functions

I tried this code...

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require("../key/secretkey.json");

import {dialogflow, BasicCard, SimpleResponse, List, Carousel} from 'actions-on-google';


admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://dburl.com"
});

const getSomethingPromize = admin.database().ref(`/user_list/`).orderByChild('blood_group');


const app = dialogflow();
app.intent('getLocation', async (conv:any, parameters) => {
    console.log("params", parameters);

    return getSomethingPromize.equalTo(parameters.blood_group)
            .once('value')
            .then((snapshot) => {

                const childCount = snapshot.numChildren();
                let message = "";
                let singleRecord;

                switch (childCount) {

                    case 0:
                        message = `No Record`;
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        singleRecord = snapshot.val();
                        singleRecord =  singleRecord[Object.keys(singleRecord)[0]];
                        message = `1 Record`;
                        getBasicCard(conv, singleRecord);
                        break;

                    default: 
                        let myItems = {};

                        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {

                            const entity = childSnapshot.val();
                            const state:any = parameters.indian_states;

                            if (entity.state.toLowerCase() !== state.toLowerCase()){                                
                                return;
                            }

                            myItems[entity.name] = {
                                synonyms: [
                                    entity.name,
                                ],
                                title: `  ${entity.name}  `,
                                description: ` Contact : ${entity.phone} ${entity.phone2}, ${entity.city}, ${entity.state}, ${entity.pincode}  `,
                            };

                        });


                        message = `Multiple Records`;


//ISSUE HERE
                        conv.close(new List({
                            title: `List Title`,
                            items: myItems,
                        }));
                }


                return getSimpleResponse(conv, parameters, message);
            });
});

function getSimpleResponse(conv, parameters, message=null){
    let displayMessage = message;

    if (!message) {
        displayMessage = `Sorry! No Record Found`;
    }
    return conv.close(new SimpleResponse({
        text: displayMessage,
        speech: displayMessage

    }));
}

function getBasicCard(conv, singleRecord){
    return conv.close(new BasicCard({
        text: `${singleRecord.blood_group}, ${singleRecord.state}`,
        subtitle: `Contact : ${singleRecord.phone} ${singleRecord.phone2}, ${singleRecord.city}, ${singleRecord.state}, ${singleRecord.pincode}, ${singleRecord.comment}  `,
        title: `${singleRecord.name}`,
        display: 'CROPPED',
    }));
}
export const fulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**Issue is :** When i Tried to Close Convo by Sending Rich List Card, the Convo remains Open.

Hence, on Stackdriver i am Issued with

> "MalformedResponse: 'final_response' must be set"

I am Referencing this Docs
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#list

Comment: In addition to a rich response like a card, you need to return a simple response.

Comment: @NickFelker As you can in last its 
`return getSimpleResponse(conv, parameters, message);` . 
I expect it to run each time . I still can't figure out where i am wrong. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can only close the conversation with a [SimpleResponse](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#simple_responses). According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits), "Your final response must be a single simple response with a 60-character limit on its textToSpeech and displayText values".

Comment: Yup Thats true, but have a look at this.. I guess this is not issue here.
https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-conversation-components-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js#L419

Here Basic Card is also used to close convo.

Comment: Hm, that might be a bug with the "Conversation Exits" doc that I shared. Another issue that I am seeing with the code is that it sets a List before the Simple Response in the conv object, which is prohibited per https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses (see Rich responses#Requirements). 

Can you first trying call ```getSimpleResponse``` and then return ```conv.close(new List { ... })```?

Comment: Tried that too but no luck.. here is complete reference to code..
https://github.com/deepak1725/google-assistant/blob/master/functions/src/index.ts
Please let me know if you can spot anything bad.
TIA